# Using Mail.php it showing the following error?

Tags: php, ssl, smtp, gmail

While using mail.php it shows following error

Failed to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 [SMTP: Failed to connect socket: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. (code: -1, response: )]

Answer (score 0):

Try It..

```
{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}
```

or

```
{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}
```